# Indexing Copernicus Global Land Service data into ODC

Tags: netcdf, open-data-cube, indexing, copernicus

I would like to index Copernicus Global Land Service data (that we can find in this site: https://land.copernicus.vgt.vito.be/manifest/) into Open Data Cube.

How can I do it without the need to download data locally?

I did it by download data locally, but I need to do it without the need to download data locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [eodatasets3](https://eodatasets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) library to index data hosted remotely, I've done it by indexing official Copernicus Global Land Cover data you can find in [this](https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vito.landcover.global) S3 bucket (data access is documented [here](https://lcviewer.vito.be/about)).

By using the [`DatasetPrepare`](https://eodatasets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#preparing-metadata) object, specifying a remote dataset location, you can call the [`note_measurement`](https://eodatasets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?eodatasets3.DatasetPrepare.note_measurement#eodatasets3.DatasetPrepare.note_measurement) method by passing a remote file (i.e. a GeoTIFF tile), the library takes care of downloading the file, reading the metadata, and generating an EO3 document you can index in ODC, without the need of keeping the file locally afterward.

```py
DATASET_LOCATION = 'https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/vito.landcover.global/v3.0.1/2015/E080N60/'
TILE_URI = 'E080N60_PROBAV_LC100_global_v3.0.1_2015-base_Discrete-Classification-proba_EPSG-4326.tif'

p = DatasetPrepare(
   dataset_location=DATASET_LOCATION,
   allow_absolute_paths=True
)
...
p.note_measurement(measurement_title, DATASET_LOCATION + TILE_URI)
dataset_doc = p.to_dataset_doc()
serialise.to_doc(dataset_doc)
```

Notice the usage of `allow_absolute_paths` as specified in the docs.
Unfortunately, the library doesn't work for multi-band files ([see issue](https://github.com/opendatacube/eo-datasets/issues/221)), in that case, you have to implement a preparation script to create the EO3 documents, but I'm sure this doesn't prevent you to reference remote datasets in the EO3. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it as soon as possible and I will give you my feedback.

Answer (score 1):

As part of Digital Earth Africa, I prepared a script that downloads, converts and uploads the Copernicus GLS data along with metadata. The [script is available here](https://github.com/digitalearthafrica/deafrica-scripts/blob/main/deafrica/data/copernicus_gls.py).

As far as I know, there is no way to index the data directly.

Comment: Ok, I understand! Thank you for your help! 

A solution would be to load everything to aws first and then use the stac-to-dc method to index data from s3. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yep, that's right!

Comment: Ok, I will try and if I succeed I will let you know. if you have any suggestions I will be happy to hear it.